# Error in django when I add two new fields to a class model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a class called Difference in my script "myProject.models.difference.py" that is:

```
class Difference(models.Model):
    comparator = models.ForeignKey(ScenarioComparator, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    summary = models.CharField('summary',max_length=900000)
```

And in my script "myProject.admin.scenario.py" I have the corresponding admin class:

```
class DifferenceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     list_display = ("comparator","summary",)
```

But I need to add two fields more to my Class Difference:

```
class Difference(models.Model):
    comparator = models.ForeignKey(ScenarioComparator, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    summary = models.CharField('summary',max_length=900000)
    diff_class = models.CharField('diff_class',max_length=1000)
    diff_field = models.CharField('diff_field',max_length=500)
```

After that I read the next error: "no such column: myproject_difference.diff_class".
But if I comment the new fields diff_class, diff_field of this way:

```
class Difference(models.Model):
    comparator = models.ForeignKey(ScenarioComparator, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    summary = models.CharField('summary',max_length=900000)
    #diff_class = models.CharField('diff_class',max_length=1000)
    #diff_field = models.CharField('diff_field',max_length=500)
```

Then the error disappears. ¿What must I do in order to add the new fields?

Comment: did you migrate models? if error comes while creating migration, in migration folder inside your app, delete migrations from latest to oldest untill you don't get error while creating migration. and also share error log.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a database migration. Save your model:

```
class Difference(models.Model):
    comparator = models.ForeignKey(ScenarioComparator, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    summary = models.CharField('summary',max_length=900000)
    diff_class = models.CharField('diff_class',max_length=1000)
    diff_field = models.CharField('diff_field',max_length=500)
```

Then do the following two `manage.py` commands:

```
$ python3 manage.py makemigrations
$ python3 manage.py migrate
```

You will need to do this every time you make changes to *models.py*

Answer (score 0):

After adding fields to your model, you must make migrations to add the columns to your database

run these two commands

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `myProject.models` folder, is there an `__init__.py` file? Inside of it, you'll need this:

```
from .difference import *
```

When you have models in a different .py file than models.py, you need to import them in the **init**.py file, or else the Django app will not know that it's there.

When you did `python manage.py makemigrations` did it create migrations files in the migrations folder?

Comment: Yes, I have __init__.py but it is empty. . Not create, I saw the error is why django need a defoult value to that new class

Comment: You don't need `diff_class` inside the Charfield(). It should be `diff_class = models.CharField(max_length=1000)`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to write a defoult value for `diff_class` and `diff_field`. When you run `python manage.py makemigrations` it appears a warning saying you need defoult values.

So I write

```
class Difference(models.Model):
    comparator = models.ForeignKey(ScenarioComparator, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    summary = models.CharField('summary',max_length=900000)
    diff_class = models.CharField('diff_class',max_length=1000,default = 'class')
    diff_field = models.CharField('diff_field',max_length=500, default= 'field')
```